# Ubuntu 16.04 dual boot w/ Windows 10 froze completely while using Android Studio. What should I do?

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, android-studio

I was using Android Studio 2.3.3 on my machine(4 GB RAM, 64 bit). The Android Studio was working fine while writing code but when I launched the Emulator(Nexus 5) the OS froze completely(not even Keyboard and Mouse were working). I had to use [REISUB](https://askubuntu.com/a/36717/707627) to come out of the situation.  I have never experienced anything like this before(It was the first time I launched the Emulator). Earlier I used to run Android Studio on Windows 10 on this machine but never faced such a problem. What should I do, should I stop using Android Studio on Ubuntu or is there an alternative?

Comment: Show me the `terminal` output of `free -h` and `swapon -s`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official documentation (https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#Requirements):

- 3Gb RAM **minimum** for IDE and 1Gb more for emulator.

So I think that your system is short. So... how much RAM are you assigning to the emulator?

Comment: Thank you! Looks like I have to increase the RAM of my laptop.

Comment: I think so, yes :)